# 2d char Array printing squares. How do I fix it?

Tags: c++, struct

I'm trying to code a tic tac toe game.
This is my struct game:

```
typedef struct {
    char tabuleiro[3][3];
    int casas[9];
    jogador* p;
} jogo;
```

I have a new game function that looks like this:

```
void novoJogo(jogo* j, jogador* p) {
    int aux = 1;
    j->p = p;

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
        j->casas[i] = i+1;

    for (int k = 0; k < 3; ++k) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
            j->tabuleiro[k][i] = (char) aux;
            aux++;
        }
    }
    jogar(j);
}
```

Everything looks ok to me, but every time I'm trying to print *tabuleiro*, I get this:

[image]

I was expecting to have something like:

```
1 | 2 | 3
4 | 5 | 6
7 | 8 | 9
```

This is my print function. I have tested a few things and I don't thing the bug is here, but here you go:

```
void print(jogo* j) {
    for (int k = 0; k < 3; ++k) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
            if (i == 0)
                cout << j->tabuleiro[k][i] << " | ";
            else if (i == 2)
                cout << " | " << j->tabuleiro[k][i] << endl;
            else
                cout << j->tabuleiro[k][i];
        }
    }
}
```

I also think it's worth pointing it out that I'm using Jetbrains' Clion as my Ide.
Does anyone knows what's happening here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make it `cout << int(j->tabuleiro[k][i])`. You are printing a character with ASCII code 1, not the character `'1'`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik this worked! The thing is: *tabuleiro* won't always have integers. In fact, as soon as the game starts it'll quickly be filled with 'X's and 'O's.

Comment: Then change `j->tabuleiro[k][i] = (char) aux` to `j->tabuleiro[k][i] = '0' + aux`, and you can print it normally. Decide whether the array is going to hold characters or integers, and stick with it.

Comment: The key is [ASCII Table and Description](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: Thanks everyone! @IgorTandetnik solution has worked just fine.